# Procedure created with compilation errors. payment_count(l_p_count); *

Tags: plsql

Create a procedure named 'payment_count' which accepts one output parameter p_count with number as its data type. This procedure should print the count of successful payments (response_msg as 'Successful') with alias name as 'successful_payment_count'.
Hints: Procedure name : payment_count
Output parameter : p_count
Table used : payment_authorization
Function used : count

```
create or replace procedure payment_count(p_count output number)
as
begin
select count(response_msg='Successful') into successful_payment_count from payment_authorization;
return successful_payment_count;
end;
/
```

[schema payment_authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwIyu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a task in an exam?
Sounds so... anyway:

You have to change keyword output to OUT, change the COUNT(response_msg='Successful') to COUNT(*) and add response_msg='Successful' to the where clause of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure payment_count(p_count out number)
as
begin

    select count(response_msg) as successful_payment_count 
    into p_count
    from payment_authorization
    where response_msg = 'Successful';

end;
/
```